# Do I need to worry about varying boost pressure when installing an electric supercharger?

Tags: engine, engine-theory, super-charger

Do I require to vary the boost pressure with respect to an increase or decrease of throttle (engine rpm)?

*Note: The supercharger is electrically driven (motor) and not by engine crankshaft.

Comment: An electric supercharger? You mean like those leaf blower motors? What did you put that in?

Comment: Well yes, something like that...

Comment: That "supercharger" is more of a air flow restrictor than anything.

Comment: Supercharging adds restrictions?!

Comment: No. The leaf blower electric motor is getting in the way. Those things don't do anything. What car did you put this in?

Comment: No, I haven't used it yet and this ain't a car it's a bike...

Comment: Is it a 2 stroke bike?

Comment: And yes not a leaf blower but something that suits my engine( 149 cc(9.31 cubic inch), 13.1 PS)

Comment: 4 stroke bike it is...

Comment: How will you power the "supercharger"? Those bikes dont have enough current to drive a powerful 12V motor.

Comment: It's going to be a motor-generator assembly. A DC generator.

Comment: Well, good luck on the invention. Don't waste too much money on it. This is a path commonly taken by tinkerers and it rarely amounts to anything. Just be pragmatic about your expectations.

Comment: Thanks... But what about the variation in boost pressure?

Comment: Is the motorcycle carburated?

Comment: To be motorcycle and fi

Comment: I dont understand your answer. :)

Comment: @racefever, Related if you missed it:  http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/27626/12030

Comment: Ah, thanks @JPhi1618. Ok, then this is a duplicate question because this falls inside the scope of the one you linked.

Comment: Actually both of these are my threads, but the password to previous account was forgotten so. And also I had doubt related to boost variation which I wasn't able to clear from that question...

Comment: Also, what @user16006 is doing is an uncommon modification which does not really fit the rules of the site. He/she also seems to be looking for answers to an invention rather to a mechanical problem.

Comment: @racefever it's within the scope, it's a performance modification.

Comment: @user16006 Click the contact us link at the bottom of the page select merge accounts for the request and fill in the required information. That will get you access to your old question.

Comment: @Movemorecommentslinktotop Thanks for the heads up. :)

Comment: @user16006 Also, edit your question to clarify what you are trying to do. A lot of it has been addressed in the comments but really should be in the question so other users don't have to read all the comments to figure out what you are trying to do. Otherwise your question will likely get closed as too broad.

Answer (score 5):

I gotta first apologize to user16006. I was looking for ways to stop you from modifying your motorcycle because the idea seemed silly. But who am I to do that? I mean, modding cars is one of my passions. I'm gonna stop being a dumbass and try to help you.

On your motorcycle, you want to limit boost pressure to when the throttle is fully open. The reason is that the engine is tuned to provide the most fuel and timing under those conditions. If you are not going full throttle, the engine is tuned to save fuel. When you boost an engine you need more fuel. To limit damaging the engine, just turn on the supercharger during full throttle with a microswitch.

Now, you are going to be putting more air into the engine. You need to balance out the ratio between air/fuel. A fuel injected engine means you will either need a bigger injector from a bigger CC engine, or put another injector that only works when the supercharger does.

You are also going to need to tune the engine in order to get the most performance out of it. It depends on how much boost you can get out of it. Get yourself a boost gauge from a diesel vehicle (you can find those in scrap yards) and hook it to the intake manifold. For every .3 bar of boost you are going to want to test removing one degree of timing.

Now, to directly answer your question:

> Do I require to vary boost pressure with respect to increase or decrease of throttle (engine rpm)?

In *your* case the answer is yes.

Good luck OP! :)

Comment: Pretty cool answer.

Comment: You are saying 3° of timing per bar (or 14 psi) of boost? That's good to know.

Comment: [Leaf-Blower Supercharging a 1978 Chevrolet Monza Spyder](http://youtu.be/U81_0waqEWA)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 That is just a very safe approach since I don't have a clue as to what timing the OP's motor runs. In turbo Porsches I actually add timing at the top if the cams will take it.

Comment: @Zaid I do love some Roadkill. :D

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to say it's not necessary here.

An "electric supercharger" like a leaf blower is more a pump than a compressor. The amount of extra air that isn't that much; it should be quite readily compensated for by the fuel injection management.

Comment: Someone remind me to post up calculations when I have some time

Comment: How do you know how big is the supercharger? If someone would disconnect Mercedes compressor from the belt and installed suitably powerful electric motor to drive it - would you still call it a leaf blower?

Comment: @Agent_L  The 'powerful electric motor' only has 12.6volts.  How powerful of an electric motor can you have?  Additionally it's a very small motorcycle.  Do you think the tiny stator in that can drive a 'powerful electric motor'?

Comment: @Agent_L it takes a lot of energy to compress gas. It's why air-con compressors in cars remain belt-driven. If you want to run a supercharger off electricity I suspect you'd need something in the kW range to get it to work. With just 12-13 V on hand, the current demand would be huge.

Comment: @DucatiKiller You're making another assumption out of the blue. He never said it's 12V, he never said it's powered from the engine.

Comment: @Agent_L   Oh sweet irony.  It's a 12.6volt system.   The bike is a Yamaha fz 2.0 Indian version.  Your late to the conversation.  Slow down.

Comment: @Zaid It takes even more energy to power a car - yet we do have electric cars that outperform gasoline ones. And you're wrong, air-con in expensive cars is electric-driven. Home air-con is even more powerful, yet they're all electric-driven. Of course you need huge energy to run a compressor, but this is entirely different issue whether this energy comes from the shaft, turbine or extra motor. It's completely impossible to drive such demand from existing low-power electric installation, it's only reasonable to assume OP is rolling out a new one.

Comment: @DucatiKiller Maybe I missed the part where OP said it's going to be run off the existing bike electric installation, can you point me into the right direction?

Comment: The electric super charger has great theory advantages . This is a valid post .The orthodox car electric system wont hack it without doing some mods .The electric motor can easily be PWM controled for speed and hence boost . This is much better than changing blower pulleys or wasting energy in blow off valves.